# Minify HTML code without breaking inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, caching

I have been caching rendered pages to a redis cache and serving them to non logged in users as a speedy cache. The page size for most pages is hitting around 100kb. I was able to knock 20kb off the size by minifying the html before inserting it into redis, but it seems that this process breaks any inline javascript on the pages.

Am using the following PHP function to perform the minify at the moment. I have had to disable it of course, but it seems to be doing OK, just needs to be more weary of javascript.

```
function MinifyHtml($html)
{
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',     // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',     // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s',         // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/' // Remove HTML comments
    );

    $replace = array('>','<','\\1','');

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $html);

    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This might sound dumb, but have you considered not having inline JavaScript? It's a bad practice anyway.

Comment: That aside, my own server minifies HTML by just stripping out `/\r?\n\t*/` - works pretty well!

Comment: Consider gzipping it instead of minifying. You'll see the same size benefits (probably significantly better, in fact) and there'll be no change to the underlying HTML.

Comment: i had considered gzip actually, it reduces the 100kb down to around 20kb, but i have 15gb of ram free on the server so i was thinking it would be better to waste ram than waste CPU time

Answer (score 0):

Use a prebuild HTML minification tool that can handle inline javascript, see [HTMLdoc on GitHub](https://github.com/hexydec/htmldoc).

You are also using a cache, so any CPU cycles are not wasted because you are caching the output. As [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz) suggests, Gzipping your output will get far better compression and it will cost less CPU time than minification, you will get ~70% compression from gzip, but only ~15% from minification. Combine and the minification will gain you an extra ~10% of the gzipped size.

Suggest you store both the Gzipped and non-gzipped version and serve them directly from your cache based on the `Vary` header.

Answer (score -2):

I have use a PHP Function to Minify HTML and JavaScript , the extention can be found here: 
https://gist.github.com/tovic/d7b310dea3b33e4732c0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.